# Outgoing ports for making HTTP requests from Ruby on Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, httparty

My application (Ruby on Rails using jRuby, on puma, on nginx on CentOS 6) wants to make direct server-to-server requests to a remote REST API service. 
My app is in a different network from the service's network, meaning the IT department has to configure the firewall so that these requests are allowed.

They want to know

- the source (IP and port) and
- the target (IP and port)

Everything is pretty straightforward except the **source port**. Is it even possible to have my application use just one port? If not, can I at least give a range of ports? How is this configured?

Comment: while making the request with some client to external service, ruby(or in general any tcp client) would create a socket and assign port from the [dynamic range (49152-65535)](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml). You should probably get them whitelisted as source port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

I just saw the [httparty](/questions/tagged/httparty), for which you can use the `:local_port` and `:local_host` request option:

Apparently, you have to specify the local_host if you want to specify local_port, which is a limitation going all the way down to `Socket`, and maybe event `connect(2)`

```
# Get the first local IP address which is not the loopback
# There are far better way of doing this, this is just for the example
addr = Socket.ip_address_list.select(&:ipv4?).detect{|addr| addr.ip_address != '127.0.0.1'}

# Start a connection using a predefined port
HTTParty.get 'http://google.com', local_port: 60000, local_host: addr.ip_address
```

---

The reason for which we have to specify both local_host and local_port if we want to override the local port is that Socket uses `Addrinfo.getaddrinfo`, which returns loopback addresses if only the port is specified.

This is due to `getaddrinfo(3)`:

> If the AI_PASSIVE flag is not set in hints.ai_flags, then the returned socket addresses will be suitable for use with connect(2), sendto(2), or sendmsg(2). If node is NULL, then the network address will be set to the loopback  interface  address  (INADDR_LOOPBACK for IPv4 addresses, IN6ADDR_LOOPBACK_INIT for IPv6 address); this is used by applications that intend to  communicate  with peers running on the same host.

And AI_PASSIVE is not set in this case, as we don't want to `bind` but to `connect`.

Using the loopback address, the outside network is thus unreachable, which is why we need to specifcy the local_host too.

---

#### original answer

You can do this by first creating the `Net::HTTP` instance then configuring `local_port` (a R/W attribute) before starting the connection.

If you use any other mean for establishing the connection, you might want to check the documentation to see if there's such method available.

```
http = Net::HTTP.new(address, port)
http.local_port = 666
http.local_host = 'your ip address'
http.start do
  # whatever
end
```

The `local_port` is an `attr_accessor` and `@local_port` is used directly to open the TCP socket: `TCPSocket.open(conn_address, conn_port, @local_host, @local_port)`

Comment: Thanks, got it. Now interestingly `HTTParty.get 'http://google.com'` works fine, but `HTTParty.get 'http://google.com', local_port: 60000` (or any other valid port) yields "Errno::EHOSTUNREACH: Failed to open TCP connection to google.com:80 (No route to host - connect(2) for "google.com" port 80)"

Comment: maybe you simply can't use port 60000?

Comment: For a **forbidden** port (e.g. 10) I am getting an explicit forbidden error "Errno::EACCES: Failed to open TCP connection to google.com:80 (Permission denied - bind(2) for nil port 10)" vs. the error above.

Comment: @AlexanderPresber I was not talking about a forbidden port, but anyway the error is not what I though. I'm still looking for the exact reason **why** it doesn't work, but in the mean time I updated my answer with a solution, you have to provide the local_host too ;-)